# Update sql database using variables from Python Flask HTML list

Tags: python, flask, pyodbc, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I am trying to create a Website form (using Python Flask and WTForms and pyodbc for my database connection). I have a sql server database that is displaying the records to update in the html.

My goal is to update the "Unit price" and "discount" for each record in the database. The form I created requires an input in each of these fields from the user. Because that database data is displayed in a list, I'm not sure how to match up the data back to the database.

When I submit the form as is, only the first record is inserted into the database and [This is what the form looks in my testing environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWKZH.png) (please forgive the horrible formatting). The first column is for the "unit price" and the second is for the "discount" the only record inserted into the database is the first one and the element and element name are not mapped properly.

Is there a way to reference the columns in "elementdata"? (ex: elementdata.UniqueKey)

How can I create the connection between the data displayed in the html to the data inserted to the database?

EDIT: I watched a few of Corey Schafer's video's on youtube and found them helpful but they haven't quite solved my problem.(https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCCezIgC97PvUuR4_gbFUs5g)

I'm currently heading into the direction of creating my own list and then calling that list in the HTML. So instead of

elementdata = cur.execute("SELECT UniqueKey, Element, ElementName, Quantity FROM FakePricingData WHERE ClientName=clientname").fetchall()

I tried:

uniquekey = cur.execute("SELECT UniqueKey FROM FakePricingData WHERE ClientName=clientname").fetchall()

element = cur.execute("SELECT Element FROM FakePricingData WHERE ClientName=clientname").fetchall()

elementname = cur.execute("SELECT ElementName FROM FakePricingData WHERE ClientName=clientname").fetchall()

elementdata = [uniquekey, element, elementname]

However, when referencing elementdata[0], insead of getting just the uniquekey, I get the entire first row.

How can I get what I'm looking for? I would appreciate any help I can get!

```js
@app.route("/VendorPricing/Example", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def vendorpricing():
    clientname = "Example Credit Union"
    elementdata = cur.execute("SELECT UniqueKey, Element, ElementName, Quantity FROM FakePricingData WHERE ClientName=clientname").fetchall()
    form = VendorPricingForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        for elementdata in elementdata:
            loggedinuserid = current_user.get_id()
            query = "INSERT INTO FakeQuoteData (UniqueKey, Element, ElementName, Quantity, UnitPrice, Discount, ClientName, SubmittedBy, LoggedInUserId) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);"
            query_values = [form.uniquekey.data, form.element.Element, 'NULL', '0', form.unitprice.data, form.discount.data, clientname, form.submittedby.data, loggedinuserid]
            cur.execute(query, query_values)
            cur.commit()
            flash('Your pricing has been submitted!', 'success')
            return redirect(url_for('welcome'))
    return render_template('vendorpricing.html', form=form, clientname=clientname, elementdata=elementdata)
    
    
    
    ------ form ------
    
class VendorPricingForm(FlaskForm):
      unitprice = IntegerField('Unit Price', validators=[DataRequired()])
      discount = IntegerField('Discount')
      uniquekey = StringField('Unique Key')
      submittedby = StringField('Submitted By', validators=[DataRequired()])
      submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

```html
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
<h2>{{ title }}</h2>

<body>
    <form method="POST" action="">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        <div class="vendor-form-group">
            {{ form.unitprice.label(class="form-control-label") }}
            {{ form.discount.label(class="form-control-label") }}
            {% for elementdata in elementdata %}
            <p>
                {{ elementdata }}
                {{ form.unitprice }}
                {{ form.discount }}
            </p>
            {% endfor %}
            {{ form.submittedby.label(class="form-control-label") }}
            <p>{{ form.submittedby }}</p>
            {{ form.submit }}
        </div>
    </form>
</body>

{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try InputRequired() instead of DataRequired()

Comment: Adding an explanation of how this change affects the query would very helpful.